# Cant Load my image to picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am trying to load picture into a picturebox in c#, But sometimes it gives me exception and some times it works fine but not showing the image on the picture box.
here is my code

```
try
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\digit\\Desktop\\C.png");
    picBoxMain.Image = bmp;
    picBoxMain.Visible = true;
    InitializeComponent();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error "+ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Is `picBoxMain` initialized before calling `InitializeComponent();`?

Comment: normally this should throw null exception

Answer (score 1):

**First**, I'd put the `InitliazeComponent` method first (I assume this is a constructor)

```
try
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\digit\\Desktop\\C.png");
    picBoxMain.Image = bmp;
    picBoxMain.Visible = true;

}catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error "+ex.Message);
}
```

**Second** - check if the image has really that path (you can do it in your code - use`File.Exists path)`).

**Third** - check if the image has some transparency: maybe the size of the picture box is too small and you are displaying the transparent part.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be after InitializeComponent();

Try this..

```
    try
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\digit\\Desktop\\C.png");
        picBoxMain.Image = bmp;
        picBoxMain.Visible = true;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error "+ex.Message);
    }
```